# 301 Redirect /services.asp to /services/

Tags: url, redirect, url-rewriting, web-config

I recently transitioned a classic asp site to using url rewrites via the web.config file.

The issue I am having is that whereas I created a rule to rewrite a page such as www.myurl.com/services.asp to simply www.myurl.com/services/ the old page will still come up in search results.

Using classic asp, how can I do the redirect detecting the .asp extension and doing a 301 to the proper format?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sorry, when I meant to write when I browse to the url with the .asp it shows the page fine, but without the rewrite rule being applied.

Comment: This is my url rewrite             

   <rule name="services" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^services" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="services.asp" />
              </rule>

Comment: Would placing this <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/services/" /> in the <head> solve my issue and get services.asp removed from serps?

Answer (score 0):

This rule will do simple redirect from `www.myurl.com/services.asp` to `www.myurl.com/services`

```
<rule name="services.asp to services">
    <match url="^services.asp$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="services" />
</rule>
```